# sending multidimensional objects in c# mvc, and rendering individual attributes, to c# mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm not entirely sure I've worded the title to this issue correctly, so firstly my apologies.

I have an issue relating to values (and the count of said values) being rendered from a database query using LINQ within a C# MVC controller to a view. The view is to use the first value as a visible value, then use the second value to determine the CSS applied to the first value's element.

As an example, I have a sequence

```
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 2, 2 etc.
```

and the value of runs for this would be

```
3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3 etc.
```

Each value is to be rendered in a separate div for screen wrapping, but depending on the run of said number will be coloured to reflect there being a run of numbers;

```
<div style="float:left; background-color:red">1</div> //
<div style="float:left; background-color:red">1</div> // three the same = red
<div style="float:left; background-color:red">1</div> //
<div style="float:left; background-color:yellow">2</div> // two the same = yellow
<div style="float:left; background-color:yellow">2</div> //
<div style="float:left; background-color:green">4</div> // single instance = green
<div style="float:left; background-color:red">5</div> // etc.

etc.
```

The controller contains an ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult getDataAndDisplay (int bar)
{
    var runOfNumbers = new ???;
    using (var foo = new Entities())
    {
        initialRunOfNumbers = (from n in foo.Numbers
                            where foo.bar == bar
                            select n.number).ToArray();
        // loop through numbers and get counts set for each number - the code for calculating the run count is sorted

        // end result should be pairs of values; number, countOfNumberRun

        // assign eventual list(?) of pairs to runOfNumbers
    }

    return View("numbers", "show", new {RunOfNumbers = runOfNumbers} )
}
```

And the view simply prints out each number with suitable formatting:

```
@model NumberRunMachine.Models.NumberRunModel;
//traditional HTML header code, get to body
@foreach(var item in Model.RunOfNumbers)
{
    <div class="run-of-number-style-@item.countOfNumberRun">@item.number</div>
}
```

CSS:

```
.run-of-number-style-1
{
    background-color:green;
}
.run-of-number-style-2
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
.run-of-number-style-3
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

My main issue is how to best collate the numbers and run counts together to send to the view, which allows for rendering the separate aspects of each pair as needed? I've looked at anonymous objects, jagged arrays, multidimensional arrays, lists of arrays (explicit use of ToList() etc.) - and either I'm not getting code right, or there just aren't any intellisense helpers to show which one allows for the granularity I require in the view.

I can get a multidimensional array to send values, but the view doesn't let me pull individual values out. What is the best practice? What am I missing?

EDIT: Adding the model so people get the full MVC :)

```
public class PageRunModel : Model
{
    // I am currently getting all information as a multidimensional array, but can't separate it out
    public byte[,] RunOfNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue you have could be that you are sending an anonymous object as a model at the controller, but the view expects a specific class `NumberRunMachine.Models.NumberRunModel`.

In order to send data to the view, I can think of 3 alternatives:

**1. Use ViewData to send additional data to view**

You can use the `ViewDataDictionary` to send more data to the view, in order to not altering the main model. Suppose you have a `UserInfo` class that you want to send to the view:

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult getDataAndDisplay (int bar)
{
    //...
    ViewData["userInfo"] = userInfo;
    //...
    return View("numbers", "show", new NumberRunModel(){RunOfNumbers = runOfNumbers} )
}
```

*View*

```
@{
    UserInfo user = ViewData["userInfo"] as UserInfo;
}
<b>User name:</b> @user.Name
<!-- And so on... -->
```

**2. Create a new custom ViewModel class**

You can define another ViewModel class just for this view, and add properties as needed:

*ViewModel*

```
public class DataDisplayViewModel
{
  public UserInfo User { set; get; }
  public byte[,] RunOfNumbers { set; get; }
}
```

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult getDataAndDisplay (int bar)
{
    //...
    return View("numbers", "show", new DataDisplayViewModel(){User = userInfo, RunOfNumbers = runOfNumbers});
}
```

*View*

```
@model DataDisplayViewModel

<!-- ... -->

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RunOfNumbers.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    <div class="run-of-number-style-@Model.RunOfNumbers[i,0].ToString()">
        @Model.RunOfNumbers[i,1].ToString()
    </div>
}

<!-- ... -->

<b>User name:</b> @Model.User.Name
<!-- And so on... -->
```

**3. Use a dynamic model**

As of MVC3, you can use a `dynamic` model for passing an anonymous type's object to views:

*Controller*

```
public ActionResult getDataAndDisplay (int bar)
{
    //...
    return View("numbers", "show", new {User = userInfo, RunOfNumbers = runOfNumbers});
}
```

*View*

```
@model dynamic

<!-- ... -->

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.RunOfNumbers.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    <div class="run-of-number-style-@Model.RunOfNumbers[i,0].ToString()">
        @Model.RunOfNumbers[i,1].ToString()
    </div>
}

<!-- ... -->

<b>User name:</b> @Model.User.Name
<!-- And so on... -->
```

If you are using MVC below version 3, you can check this post: [Passing anonymous objects to MVC views and accessing them using dynamic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidebb/archive/2009/12/18/passing-anonymous-objects-to-mvc-views-and-accessing-them-using-dynamic.aspx)

Comment: I'd not have thought that was the issue, to be honest; I have the model looking as below:

    public class NumberRunModel : Model
    {
        // I am currently getting *all* information as a multidimensional array, but can't separate it out
        public byte[,] runOfNumbers { get; set; }
    }

I'd prefer to change the method of passing the information, rather than changing the nature of the model; it becomes more about the method of data transmission, as I'll be eventually passing other values through to the view (like user information etc).

apologies for code; can't ever render it :S

Comment: I see, that's why you are using an anonymous type. I will make some more editings and corrections to my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks, I've ended up using the dynamic model as you've described, its doing what I need.